# Session logged out too soon

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Microsoft Identity and users are complaining that they keep getting redirected to the login screen after only around 30 minutes of inactivity.  I've set it up with 60 minutes in the ExpireTimeSpan, but it's never lasting anywhere near that long.  Any suggestions?

This is what I have in the Startup.cs file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IRFDbRepository, RFDbRepository>();
    var connection = _configuration.GetConnectionString("RFDbConnection");
    services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(_configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
    services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.AllowAreas = true;
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
    });

    services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
    services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<UserRole>, RoleStore>();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IRFDbRepository rFDbRepository)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    loggerFactory.AddFile(_configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:LogFile"));
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to set `RememberMe` as `True` in `var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);`

Comment: Tried that now and no different I'm afraid. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally found the root of this problem.

There is an issue with Identity in ASP.NET Core 2.1 whereby if you have implemented your own version of the UserStore but not IUserSecurityStampStore, most functionality regarding security stamps will be skipped.

When you call AddIdentity() it does a validation check on the securityStamp every 30 minutes.

This results in the confusing behaviour that the user is logged out after 30 minutes, even though the cookies did not expire.

There is a fix for this coming in ASP.NET Core 2.2 apparently, further details here

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1880

In the meantime, you can either get your UserStore to implement IUserSecurityStampStore, or do what I did as a quick fix for now, by adding this to your startup.cs which increases the time between failures from 30 minutes to 10 hours.

services.Configure(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(10));

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer just changes the issue from happening every 30 minutes to every 10 hours which isn't ideal.

In my case, I am not storing this type of user in the database at all, so of course the security stamp can't be checked - so in my case I just disabled that validation like so:

```
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
            {
                opt.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = (ctx) =>
                {
                    // Do not validate principal (i.e. security stamp) for our custom users
                    // the default behavior will log them out every SecurityStampValidatorOptions.ValidationInterval
                    if (ctx.Principal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == CmsClaimTypes.ClaimType)) return Task.CompletedTask;
                    return SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync(ctx);
                };
            });
```